# Matlab figures - make two graphs look more close to each other

Tags: matlab

[image]

I have two "graphs" which differ from each other at a maximum of 0.006 , if one doesn't inspect the graph one might think that there is a large difference . How can i make them look more close to each other. I would want the scale not to change if I zoom the picture ,how can i do that

Look at the y axis , these two graphs are close to each other but look far from each other if you really don't  consider the y axis

[image]

Comment: Uh... picture? Code?  In what sense do they "differ"?  Why do you want there to be no distinguishing difference if you zoom in?  Are you trying to fool somebody? :)

Comment: how can I add this picture here I want to show you @rayryeng

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post - You have enough reputation points to do it.

Comment: BTW, if you are trying to calculate two signals and showing that they're exactly the same, unless both input signals are the same, it is very unlikely that you will get them to be exactly equal due to floating point inaccuracy and roundoff.

Comment: @rayreng please take a look

Comment: Ah I see now.  Yeah the picture helped lol.  Is it important that you maintain the `y` scale?  Specifically, did you try normalizing the `y` values so that both graphs are on the same scale... like `[0,1]`?

Comment: @rayryeng no i just used "plot" for the blue graph and "bar" for the other "graph" it is actually bars the "black thing"

Comment: Yeah the graphs look different because it looks like you're plotting them with different scales.  You need to make sure that both graphs are being plotted with respect to the same scale.

Comment: how do i plot them on the same scale :( , Iam so bad at matlab pictures

Comment: I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about changing the `y` values when plotting, you need to make sure that each graph is plotted with respect to the same scale.  One thing you could try is to normalize both plots so that the `y` values both fall within a certain dynamic range.  One popular range is simply `[0,1]`.  As such, given your two signals `y1` and `y2` that you want to plot, do something like this:

```
y1_new = (y1 - min(y1)) / (max(y1) - min(y1));
y2_new = (y2 - min(y2)) / (max(y2) - min(y2));
```

You would then plot `y1_new` and `y2_new` on the same figure.  The above transformation is a very standard way of taking a set of points or input data and transforming it so that the minimum is 0 and the maximum is 1.

Give that a whirl and see how it goes!

Comment: i just want to show that it is possible to make a normal approximation of the "black mass"

Comment: Cool... so how does this apply to me?  Did you even try what I wrote?

Comment: @rayreng wow it worked , can i read about this method so that i can explain in my report what i did :)

Comment: @Danny - lol you're welcome.  Right here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling.  Your particular point of interest is the **Rescaling** section of the Wiki article.

Comment: @rayreng It doesn't say much about  that transform on wiki, but i have added the new picture and now it actually looks like the black mass is above the blue graph in some places which of course is not desireable , maybe i should use some other transform, by taking the log of the values or the square root

Comment: @Danny - That's something you could try. Perhaps take a `log`, then normalize.  Also, there's nothing really much to say about that transform. It's so simple in nature that there isn't much more to say about it!

Answer (score 0):

A maximum difference of .006 is rather significant, when the maximal value of one of the curve is .001.

If the y axis ran from say 1000.000 to 1000.007, you would have a valid claim that the difference is negligible.